# Pedigree collapse and generation number

Tags: pedigree

Which generation are the descendants of the marriage of persons from different generation (e.g. person and her uncle see e.g. Pedigree of Alfonso XII of Spain here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedigree_collapse) classified to?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! I've closed this because you've essentially asked two versions of the same question, and the information given in any answers to the first one is likely to give you the information needed to answer this one as well.  You can improve the open question at any time by using the edit link under your question.  For more information on how the site works, please see the [help], especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Generally, one describes a person by the closest known relationship. For instance, everyone (through pedigree collapse) is also nth cousin to everyone else but we use call them siblings, parents, etc. (or whatever the case may be).

Comment: @bgwiehle That I understand. But my question was rather about such a case: a person marries her uncle, let us say she is from 4th generation - counting from patriarch, and he from 3rd generation. What can we say about generation of the children from that marriage? Probably they are from both 4th and 5th generations? Is there the "canonical" way of presenting such a case in descendants pedigree chart?

Comment: For ahnentafels and pedigree charts, see my answer to https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13734/numbering-and-pedigree-collapse